# Json request POST rest-assured

Tags: api, rest-assured

please help me to create the body request from the following output:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "categoryId": "4654-456465-4564",
      "fields": {
        "4564654-454646-4564": "Ano",
        "4564654-454646-4561": "Super"
      }
    }
  ],
  "lastUpdate": "1231",
  "controlStructureId": "4654-456465-4564",
  "controlId": "4654-456465-4564",
  "vehicleId": "4654-456465-4564"
}
```

My code here, but It's not correct, because I have unwanted **[ ]** in * fields* section

```
public void testPOST() {
        Map<String, Object> jsonBodyUsingMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        jsonBodyUsingMap.put("categories", Collections.singletonList(new HashMap<String, Object>() {
            {
                put("categoryId", "4654-456465-4564");
                put("fields", Arrays.asList(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                        put("4564654-454646-4561", "Super");
                        put("4564654-454646-4564", "Ano");
                }}
                ));
            }
        }
        ));
        jsonBodyUsingMap.put("lastUpdate", "1231");
        jsonBodyUsingMap.put("controlStructureId", "4654-456465-4564");
        jsonBodyUsingMap.put("controntrolId", "4654-456465-4564");
        jsonBodyUsingMap.put("vehicleId", "4654-456465-4564");
```

Comment: `fields` must be a `Map<String, Object>` and not an `Array`. So no need for `Arrays.asList(...)` just use the `HashMap` you are already creating. But you should probably use a dedicated JSON library like for instance [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove Arrays.asList() from * fields* and let only the hash map

```
public void testPOST() {
        Map<String, Object> jsonBodyUsingMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        jsonBodyUsingMap.put("categories", Collections.singletonList(new HashMap<String, Object>() {
            {
                put("categoryId", "4654-456465-4564");
                put("fields", new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                        put("4564654-454646-4561", "Super");
                        put("4564654-454646-4564", "Ano");
                }}
                );
            }
        }
        ));
        jsonBodyUsingMap.put("lastUpdate", "1231");
        jsonBodyUsingMap.put("controlStructureId", "4654-456465-4564");
        jsonBodyUsingMap.put("controntrolId", "4654-456465-4564");
        jsonBodyUsingMap.put("vehicleId", "4654-456465-4564");
```

Comment: @Toyota Any Time

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're wrapping your key/value object, the `HashMap` in an `Array` method. If you lose that, you'll get keys/values and not "brackets" (keyless list of values)

```
put("fields", new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
    put("4564654-454646-4561", "Super");
    put("4564654-454646-4564", "Ano");
}});
```